# Unable to convert value 'userAmount' to type 'Integer' for attribute 'maximum'

Tags: apex, visualforce, decimal

I am trying to set a visualforce gauge chart to have the maximum value be a currency field from the user record.

I can get the field:

```
    Decimal userAmount = [Select ISO_Goal__c From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]
[0].ISO_Goal__c.intValue();
Integer uA = userAmount.intValue();
```

I've set the value for myself to be 100.00. I can do a anonymous apex is shows up as a whole number 100. When I view my visualforce page I get the error that it cannot convert it to a integer.

```
<apex:page controller="ISOGaugeController2b"> 
<apex:chart height="175" width="250" animate="true" data="{!piedata}">
<apex:axis type="Gauge" position="gauge" title="Dan Test"
    minimum="0" maximum="uA" steps="0"/>
<apex:gaugeSeries dataField="data" donut="50"/>
</apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect `uA` to be a controller property and to see `maximum="{!uA}"` in the page.

Comment: Doesn't work, it says "unknown property 'ISOGaugeController2b.uA'".

Comment: Yes, "uA to be a controller property" means having a controller field `public Integer uA {get; set;}` and setting the amount in that field.